# Performance when converting a String to Uint32Array

Tags: javascript, string, performance, ecmascript-6, typed-arrays

I need to convert Strings to TypedArrays (and back to Strings) in ES6.
Currently this is done with the following functions:

```js
function string2array(s) {
    return Uint32Array.from(s, (c) => c.codePointAt(0));
}

function array2string(a) {
    return String.fromCodePoint(...a);
}
```

`string2array` is two times slower than `array2string`. I expected both functions to be equally fast. My notion of how they work is as follows:

```
string2array(s):
allocate memory for array of length=s.length 
foreach character (or surrogate pair):
    get codePoint
    push to array
return array

array2string(a):
allocate memory for string of lenght=a.length
foreach item in array
    get String.fromCodePoint
    push to string
return string
```

So they seem pretty comparable to me.

1. Why is string2array slower?
2. Is there a faster way for string2array?

Here is my test-case:

```js
function testConversions() {
  "use strict";
  const data = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ ";
  const iterations = 1e1;
  let a;
  let s;
  let i;

  function string2array(s) {
    return Uint32Array.from(s, (c) => c.codePointAt(0));
  }

  function array2string(a) {
    return String.fromCodePoint(...a);
  }

  console.time("s2a");
  i = iterations;
  while (i) {
    a = string2array(data);
    i -= 1;
  }
  console.timeEnd("s2a");
  console.log(a.toString());

  console.time("a2s");
  i = iterations;
  while (i) {
    s = array2string(a);
    i -= 1;
  }
  console.timeEnd("a2s");
  console.log(s);
}
testConversions();
```

Comment: You can make your code into a runnable snippet. it runs fine in chrome.

Comment: Why do you need an Uint32Array ? If you're ok with an Uint8Array, then the [TextEncoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder) and [TextDecoder](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextDecoder/) APIs are [the fastest](https://jsperf.com/str2array-vs-textencoder/1).

Comment: The notional idea of how `.from` works for a typed array is not exact.  Per [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/from#Description), first all the values to go into the typed array are collected (using the string iterator and your map function), then the typed array is created using the count of values obtained, then the array is populated with the values. This may help explain why `string2array` is slower than you expected.

Comment: @Traktor53 thanks that explains a lot. Skipped that line in the docs…

Comment: @Kaiido Uint8Array is fine, too. I hadn't TextEncoder on my radar. Thanks for the hint – works great.

Comment: @MathiasNater You're welcome, but beware the compatibility table, it's not yet widely supported by everyone. Also note that `.from` should be optimized, so your string2array should be faster than your array2string (it is on my FF, chrome optimizations for TypedArray's method are still on their way)

Answer (score 0):

Your test should be a lil different because you `string2array` is doing more than `array2string`.

If you create:
`string_2_code_point_array`
`code_point_array_2_uint_array`
`uint_array_2_string`
you will see that the last two have comparable times.